# angular 1.5 component and babel

Tags: angularjs, babeljs

so, I'm trying to use the 1.5 component feature, but coding with fat arrows. I am using babel to build the system

My component, stripped down to the bare minimum to show my problem, is thus:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .component('myComponent', {
        controller: () => {
            this.$onInit = () => {};
        },

        template: `<p>foobar1</p>`
    });
```

when I try and load this component, I get an error complaining about

```
typeError: Cannot set property '$onInit' of undefined
```

so, when I look at the sources in chrome devtools, I see

```
angular.module('myApp').component('myComponent', {
/** @ngInject */
controller: function controller() {
    undefined.$onInit = function () {};
},
template: '<p>foobar1</p>'
```

});

I would expect that I have done something very wrong, but can't see it ;)

anyone got any tips ?

thanks

Comment: if I change the controller defintion to controller: function() { then the problem goes away ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular creates new instantion of controller for every component. In ES5 we dont have classes, so we pass construction function here.

But in es6 we have class, so you can use it instead

```
let myComponent = {
    controller: myComponentController,
    template: `<p>foobar1</p>`
};

class myComponentController{
  constructor() {
    this.answer = 41;
  }
  $onInit() {
    this.answer++;
  }
};

angular.module('myApp')
  .component('myComponent', myComponent);
```

Pascal has also written something about it here: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/es6/2015/01/23/exploring-angular-1.3-using-es6.html