# Angular controllerAs and babel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, this, babeljs

I'm creating an Angular app using ES6 features, so I'm using Babel to transpile JS. I decided not to use ES6 modules, so instead of regular `es2015` preset I'm using `es2015-script`.

The problem is with the way Babel compiles arrow functions. I'm using Angular's controllerAs notation, like this

```
angular.module('appControllers')
.controller('StoryController', ['StoryProvider', (StoryProvider)=>{
    this.plaintext='test plain';
}]);
```

this code is transpiled to

```
var _this = this;

angular.module('myControllers')
.controller('StoryController', ['StoryProvider', function (StoryProvider)             
{
    _this.plaintext = 'test plain';
}]);
```

so `this` is in completely wrong scope and binding is not working. When I manually changed compiled code to

```
angular.module('myControllers')
.controller('StoryController', ['StoryProvider', function (StoryProvider)             
{
    var _this = this;
    _this.plaintext = 'test plain';
}]);
```

it all works fine.

Why is Babel setting the intermediate `_this` variable this way? is there another Babel preset to handle this properly? Should I go with ES6 modules? I had the same problem as described in this issue [angular 1.5 component and babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36363839/angular-1-5-component-and-babel) in the first place, that's why I used the `es2015-script` preset.

Comment: replacing the arrow function with regular `function()` helps, but I'd really like to use lexical `this`.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with this code;  the use of the arrow function here is wrong.  controllers are designed to have their own `this`.  the arrow function is doing what it is designed to do (lexically binds the `this` value (does not bind its own `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target`).), which is not how a controller expects to be declared.

Comment: " but I'd really like to use lexical this." you can't, unless you want to use `$scope`

Answer (score 1):

Ok so there are several approaches here

1) use ES6 `class`

```
class StoryController{
    constructor(StoryProvider){
        this.plaintext='test plain';
        this.StoryProvider=StoryProvider;
    }
}
```

this adds about 1k of helper functions, plus as you can see, we need to save injected dependencies in the constructor.

2) get rid of arrow function in the main controller definition and use it only in methods. something like

```
function StoryController(StoryProvider){
    this.plaintext='test plain';
    this.asyncTest=()=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log(this.plaintext);
        }, 100);
    };
}
```

this transpiles to a nice

```
function StoryController(StoryProvider) {
    var _this = this;

    this.plaintext = 'test plain';

    this.asyncTest = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(_this.plaintext);
        }, 100);
    }; 
}
```

which properly scopes the `_this` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The alternate solutions in your answer appear valid, but I'd like to provide an answer to the question:

> Why is Babel setting the intermediate _this variable this way?

First, some background information. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Lexical_this):

> Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own this value (a new object in case of a constructor, undefined in strict mode function calls, the context object if the function is called as an "object method", etc.). This proved to be annoying with an object-oriented style of programming.

The thing to understand about fat-arrow functions is that they aren't just a shorter syntax for creating a function - they create a function *without it's own lexical scope*. This means that when you use `this.plaintext` inside a fat-arrow function (in non-strict mode,) `this` isn't being set on the **controller** as you expect, but on the **global object**.

Now about Babel.

Babel is doing it's best to make your transpiled code behave exactly like the source (that's the point, right?) So when it has to rewrite your fat-arrow function using an ES5-compatible function declaration, it has to pull in the reference to the global object from somewhere. So, on the preceding line, it grabs a reference to it as `_this` and uses that inside your fat-arrow function, because it thinks that's what you wanted.

---

As you showed in your question, the simplest solution is to replace the fat-arrow function with a standard function declaration in the first place, so that you'll have a lexical scope to hang things on.